# Producing multiple joins with sqlalchemy statement and expression api

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, join, sqlalchemy

Consider you have the following sql to represent:
`SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user
JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id`

Now having the orm models as below:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class User(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String

class Address(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address_name = Column(String(64))
    user_id = Column(Integer)

class PostalCode(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'postal_code'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(Integer)
```

When doing simple join like:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, join
u = User
add = Address
po = PostalCode

query = select([u.id, u.name]).select_from(join(u,add, u.id = add.user_id))
print(query)
```

Will yield eqvivalent expression to above original sql.

However if I want to do something like:
`SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user
JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id
JOIN postal_code ON postal_code.id = address.id`

By writing:

```
query = select([u.id, u.name]).select_from(join(u,add, u.id = add.user_id).join(po, po.id = add.id))
print(query)
```

This yield an error saying something like:

```
Attributeerror: type object ____ has no attribute '_from_objects`
```

Any idea what is wrong with my syntax for using of two joins?
The explanation of how using one `join` is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join).

Comment: Try :

`query = select([u.id, u.name]).select_from(join(join(u,add, u.id = add.user_id),po, po.id = add.id))
print(query) `

Comment: Can you check that you've reproduced your code here correctly? Your join conditions have syntax errors.

Comment: @univerio: for the matter of fact , Nikhil suggestion seem to work great

Comment: Adding answer for future references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By subquerying a join you can achieve a multiple join :

```
query = select([u.id, u.name]).select_from(join(join(u,add, u.id = add.user_id),po, po.id = add.id)) 
print(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider predefined your foreign key fields and relationships with your models like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForiegnKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class User(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = relationship('address')

class Address(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address_name = Column(String(64))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    postal_code = relationship('postal_code')

class PostalCode(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'postal_code'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), primary_key=True)
    code = Column(Integer)
    address = relationship('address')

query = select(user.id, user.name).\
    join(address).\
    join(postal_code)

print(query)
```

Running this should produce the query from the original post.

Then magically, you can stop using join in your selects all together!

```
query = select(user.name, 
    user.address.address_name, 
    user.address.postal_code.code)
```